# Git: Download zip instead of clone, now cannot commit

Tags: git

I accidentally manage to download a repo to a new machine by hitting the "download zip" instead of doing a clone.

I notice after I did a lot of changes, and now I have problems commit and push the new changes to github, since the git repo wasn't included in the zip.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Clone the repo to another dir and copy the files over

Comment: Added a full script + screenshot for you to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone the repo, but you don't have to "copy your files over the new repo"

```
git clone http://github.com/<user>/<repo>
cd <repo>
```

With the `git --work-tree` option, you can work in your git repo while considering another folder as your working tree:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/unzipped/files add .
git status 
git commit -m "commit changes from unzipped folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a (shallow) clone into a separate directory and copy your changes over there.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple:

- you can clone the repository to a different folder and copy your changes.
- Set the current folder as git repo and pull the branch you want to merge the code with.

  ```
  cd <folder>

  # Init empty repo
  git init 

  # Add remote so you will be able to pull code from the repo
  git remote add origin <url>

  # Download the content to your repository
  git fetch

  # Merge any content you need
  git pull origin <branch name>
  ```

And now you're all set to go and your code is merged into your current branch.
As you see in the attached screenshot, there is an folder and using the `add remote` is connected to the repos and you can see all the content with all the remote branches.

[image]